# ORA-06550: NUMBER precision constraint must be in range (1 .. 38) on entity framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm blocked with an error here, basically I have a table already created before and for this table i created an auto-increment (using the next Trigger/Sequence); before continue i have to say that this table has already information inside, i don't know if can be an issue:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "schema"."sequenceNAme"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 1.00000000000000E+27 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;


create or replace TRIGGER T_unique BEFORE INSERT ON table_id
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF :NEW.idcolumn IS NULL THEN
      SELECT sequenceNAme.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.idcolumn FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
```

the `DataType` for this ID is `Float`;

When I tried to  insert into the table from oracle, it works fine.

```
insert into table_id values(null,'Tigrex','test','TestSystem');
```

this generates the auto increment correctly

Then I included it into the code using Entity framework. it looks like the next: 
[image]

but when i create the object, and save i receive the next error:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 26:
PLS-00216: NUMBER precision constraint must be in range (1 .. 38)
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PLS-00707: unsupported construct or internal error [2604]
ORA-06550: line 4, column 21:
PL/SQL: ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments: [2604], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PLS-00707: unsupported construct or internal error [2604]
ORA-06550: line 10, column 45:
PL/SQL: ORA-06544: PL/SQL: internal error, arguments: [2604], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-06550: line 9, column 14:
```

what I tried is, change the type into Entity framework to `Int32`, also change the `precision` to 20 (just to check), but I still receiving the same error.

Any idea?

My next idea is create a new table, but wont be the best solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post the insert statement generated by EF?